# Bash script: testing if floating point number is in a certain range including negative numbers

Tags: bash, comparison, bc

I'm trying to test if the variable `$test` is between `-0.9` and `0.9`. The following code works with numbers, but if `$test` is a lower case letter, it says it's a number between `-0.9` and `0.9`.

Is there a better way of doing this, so that letters are not considered to be in the range?

```
test=a

if (( $( echo "$test >= -0.9" |bc -l) )) && (( $(echo "$test <= 0.9" |bc -l) )); then
    echo "${test} is between -0.9 and 0.9"
else
    echo "${test} is NOT between -0.9 and 0.9"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if (( $( echo "$test >= -0.9" |bc -l) )) && (( $(echo "$test <= 0.9" |bc -l) )); then
```

With (assuming GNU or other enhanced bc):

```
if [[ "$test" =~ ^[[:digit:].e+-]+$ ]] && echo "$test>-0.9 && $test <=0.9" |bc -l | grep -q 1; then
```

#### How it works

- `[[ "$test" =~ ^[[:digit:].e+-]+$ ]]`

  This checks that `$test` contains only legal number characters.
- `&&`

  This continues the bc test only if `$test` passed the number check.
- `echo "$test>-0.9 && $test <=0.9" |bc -l | grep -q 1`

  This verifies that `$test` is in the range that you want.  `grep -q 1` sets the appropriate exit code for the `if` statement to use.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring the code to use Awk might be more efficient, though it requires understanding some obscure things about the shell.

```
if awk -v number="$test" 'END { exit !( \
    number !~ /[^0-9.]/ && number !~ /\..*\./ && \
    number >= -0.9 && number <= 0.9) }' /dev/null
then
    echo "$test is between -0.9 and 0.9"
else
    echo "$test is NOT between -0.9 and 0.9"
fi
```

The exit code examined by `if` is regarded as true if it's zero, which is opposite to the truth value inside the parentheses; thus `exit !(...)`. Awk's processing model requires you to read an input file; we supply `/dev/null`, and put the actual logic in the `END` block so it gets executed even when there is no input.

This checks that there is never more than one decimal point but the regex doesn't currently cope with exponential notation. Adding support for that should not be too hard, given the regex in John1024's answer.